# Getting Unexpected EOF from a UTF-16 string

Tags: javascript, utf-16

I'm using [LZstring](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html) to do a UTF-16 compression on a string and storing it in a database. Specifically, it was a `JSON.stringify`'d data stored in a [cordova.sqllite](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) db. When I retrieve the data from the db there are times when it causes **SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF**

I'm thinking that depending on the input, LZString's `compressToUTF16` function produces an invalid character. The weird thing is, it was stored in the DB properly (no unexpected EOF errors when storing into the DB).

Storing a normal string or a `compressToBase64`'d string does not cause an error so I don't think it's a problem with the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, LZString's UTF16 compression sometimes generates `\u2028` and `\u2029` characters which are treated by the parser as line breaks (see [here](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset) for more details). I replaced all occurrences of both unicodes after compression and before storage, and after retrieval and before decompression to fix the problem.

before storage

```
var dbvalue = LZString.compressToUTF16(JSON.stringify(value));
dbvalue = dbvalue.replace(/\u2028/g, '\u32800').replace(/\u2029/g, '\u32801');
```

after retrieval

```
var utfdata = dbvalue.replace(/\u32800/g,'\u2028').replace(/\u32801/g,'\u2029');
var value = JSON.parse(LZString.decompressFromUTF16(utfdata));
```

**EDITED**
The replacement character is not used by LZString and takes up less space. See [here](https://github.com/pieroxy/lz-string/issues/57#issuecomment-117810547) for more details